# are dot net exceptions dependent on computer's locale

Tags: .net, exception, localization

this is a bit of newbie question.  if i'm running my dot net application on a server configured for english location, the dot net exceptions have english text.  what happens when the server is configured for a different locale: such as french or russian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is localized.

Don't depend on the text. If you find a situation where you want to, it's probably an IOException, and using reflection to get the HResult is reliable.